# How do I reuse a Hunspell dictionary after adding my own set of words in python3? (Already tried pickling)

Tags: python, pickle, spell-checking, hunspell, spelling

I am using Hunspell with python3 for spell correction. I have added some more specific words and now I want to save the newly formed dictionary. I tried pickling it but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle HunSpell objects
```

My code so far :

```
import hunspell
spellchecker = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic', '/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff')

spellchecker.add('Revoira')
```

Now I  want to save this spellchecker instance, so that whenever I mis-spell the word "Revoira", it does correct it.